# value of variables "is" or "are" same

Tags: singular-vs-plural, mathematics

We have x=12 and y=12 .

How should we write:

> The value of x and y are same and equal

or

> The value of x and y is same and equal

Comment: Welcome! You don't necessarily need to put both "same" and "equal" if both x,y are 12. It might seem redundant to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both x and y have a value, there are two values (these happen to be equal, but in general the values don't need to be equal) So you need to pluralise "value" and use "are"

> The values of x and y are equal.

But on the other hand, if you change your perspective and treat 12 a single thing (that happens to be in both x and y) you can also say

> The variables x and y have the same value.

But you still need a plural word "variables"